# What kind of T-shirt (fabric) is this?

Tags: material-identification, clothing

I got this T-shirt at the 2023 JP Morgan Corporate Challenge 5k race.

I really like the fabric and would like to buy more shirts like it but I haven't been able to find an exact match.

I understand that it's a performance type T-shirt but this is a special quality that's not normal to generic performance polyester, and thus haven't been able to find it.

Here are two photos.  On the outside is a very light perforation kind of jersey knit, but it's more smooth on the inside.

[image: shirt 1]

[image: shirt 2]

Comment: It's really common on cycling jerseys. I have two here of different brands just like that  Some of my gym T-shirts match too. I *think* the right ones are Hanes brand, and plain colours. And I *think* that Hanes often supply sportswear to be customised for events.

Comment: Yes, mine are definitely Hanes. Nike Sphere Dry (I think, the label is quite worn) is/was similar on the outside but more textured on the inside. I meant to get some pictures last night, but left it too late

Comment: I happened to see this question again when I'm in the right place. The Hanes ones I have are "cool-dri crew neck" and "crew neck sports" and are very similar but the stitching is different, so that's not an ID. Neither are the Nike and Puma tops dare if the same fabric. On the bike stuff, it's some cheap jerseys for commuting, branded adibike and J2X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you have there is a **microfibre eyelet Dri-Fit** garment.

---

This weave is often referred to as "eyelet" (or an eyelet fabric), as well as [(mock) eyelet](https://ukfabricsonline.com/mock-eyelet-sports-fabric). I have not been able to find a distinction between the two yet.

It's similar to [Nike's *Dri-Fit*](https://www.nike.com/fi/help/a/nike-dri-fit) fabric, and you can find it labelled *Dri-Fit*, as well.

*Dri-Fit*, like 'eyelet', refers to a weave, rather than a material, and it is [apparently](https://shopwith-trea.com/dri-fit-t-shirt/) available in microfibre, (regular) polyester, pique, and heather. It does not only refer to the eyelet weave; 'mesh' and 'interlock' alternatives are [available](https://www.provisionprint.net/post/which-dri-fit-t-shirt-to-use-for-t-shirt-printing-in-singapore) as well.

[image: overview of types of related fabrics]
<sup>[source](https://monsterprints.com.sg/guide-to-dri-fit-t-shirt-printing/)</sup>

You can also find it named *cool fit* (again, if there is a distinction, it is not clear), and similar microfibre fabrics have that same "eyelet" distinction.
There might be an issue with using the term *Dri-Fit*, as it is possibly trademarked.

Comment: "Microfibre" is an annoying term because it means different things in different contexts, and even in the same context (e.g. light/compact towels)

Comment: @ChrisH True. I always thought it referred to a typical weave (one that was once lauded for being perfect for cleaning screens, IIRC). But (like the ubiquitous polyester) it is [a type of material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microfiber) (or, well, fibre used for materials), apparently with a huge range of applications.